# Automate turning off Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function app that I need to turn off every day at 5pm.

Is there a way I can automate this turn off?

I thought about a timer but I have to run through checks before it can be turned back on

Comment: I wonder, what is the use case for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to disable/enable Azure functions.

- Azure Portal
- Azure CLI
- Azure PowerShell

follow the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=powershell) for different way to Enable/Disable the Azure function

You can use **Azure CLI** & **Azure PowerShell** to automate the process.

#### Disable Azure function

Here, I am using Azure PowerShell
Update the Function app setting **`"AzureWebJobs.QueueTrigger.Disabled"`**  is **`"true"`** to disable the azure function.

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name <YOUR_FUNCTION_APP_NAME> -ResourceGroupName <YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -AppSetting @{"AzureWebJobs.QueueTrigger.Disabled" = "true"}
```

#### Enable Azure Function

Update the Function app setting **`"AzureWebJobs.QueueTrigger.Disabled"`**  is **`"false"`** to enable Azure function

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name <FUNCTION_APP_NAME> -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -AppSetting @{"AzureWebJobs.QueueTrigger.Disabled" = "false"}
```

To automate this PowerShell scripts, you need to use the **Azure Automation**, create a **runbook** and **schedule** it to **Enable/Disable the Azure function** at specific time.

#### References

- [Steps to Create Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual)
- [Schedule azure automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules)